# How to get current ad playhead time in google IMA for HTML5

Tags: html, sdk, ads, google-ima

Is there a way of retrieving current ad playhead time in google IMA for HTML5? I couldn't find it in the documentation, perhaps my eyes missed something there.

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/apis

Answer (score 0):

try using getMaxDuration() and getRemainingTime() together or you can try this https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/countdown-timer :)